# selenium - custom dropdown - selected item?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do some scraping from a Wi-Fi router configuration page using Selenium & Python (I'm just getting started with this for the first time).

The page I'm looking at seems to have some sort of custom combo box. HTML below. I can't work out how I can determine which of the two items is currently selected. Any ideas?

```
<div widget="combobox" id="mode-2g" data-bind="{wireless24g.hwmode}" data-options="{hwmode2gStore}" label-field="{WIRELESS_SETTINGS.MODE}" class="container widget-container combobox-container single">
  <div class="widget-fieldlabel-wrap ">
    <div class="widget-fieldlabel-inner">
      <label class="widget-fieldlabel combobox-fieldlabel">Mode</label>
      <span class="widget-separator">:</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-wrap-outer combobox-wrap-outer">
    <div class="widget-wrap combobox-wrap">
      <span class="text-wrap-before"></span>
      <span class="combobox-wrap-inner">
        <input class="combobox-text " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="true" value="- Please Select -" />
      </span>
      <a class="combobox-switch" tabindex="undefined">
        <span class="icon"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="hidden combobox-lists">
        <li class="combobox-list   ">
          <label for="mode-2g-option-3d1b9417-b134-b2f9-fa50-403b6ad75870" type="single" class="combobox-label single">
            <input id="mode-2g-option-3d1b9417-b134-b2f9-fa50-403b6ad75870" name="" display="802.11b/g/n/ax mixed" class="combobox-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-index="0" />
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="text">802.11b/g/n/ax mixed</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="combobox-list   ">
          <label for="mode-2g-option-be4d3df3-0134-b2f9-fa50-408a1a75e27d" type="single" class="combobox-label single">
            <input id="mode-2g-option-be4d3df3-0134-b2f9-fa50-408a1a75e27d" name="" display="802.11b/g/n/ax/be mixed" class="combobox-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-index="1" />
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <span class="text">802.11b/g/n/ax/be mixed</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </div>
      <span class="text-wrap-after"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following code:

```
ele = self.webdriver.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-bind="{wireless24g.hwmode}"]')
print(ele.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
items = ele.find_elements_by_class_name("combobox-list")
for item in items:
    print(item.get_attribute("class"), item.is_selected())
items = ele.find_elements_by_class_name("combobox-checkbox")
for item in items:
    print(item.get_attribute("class"), item.is_selected())
```

But that doesn't give any indication, just:

```
<div widget="combobox" id="mode-2g" data-bind="{wireless24g.hwmode}" data-options="{hwmode2gStore}" label-field="{WIRELESS_SETTINGS.MODE}" class="container widget-container combobox-container single"><div class="widget-fieldlabel-wrap "><div class="widget-fieldlabel-inner"><label class="widget-fieldlabel combobox-fieldlabel">Mode</label><span class="widget-separator">:</span></div></div><div class="widget-wrap-outer combobox-wrap-outer"><div class="widget-wrap combobox-wrap"><span class="text-wrap-before"></span><span class="combobox-wrap-inner"><input class="combobox-text " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="true" value="- Please Select -"></span><a class="combobox-switch" tabindex="undefined"><span class="icon"></span></a><div class="hidden combobox-lists"><li class="combobox-list   "><label for="mode-2g-option-33923a49-d134-b2f9-1048-786edd639f99" type="single" class="combobox-label single"><input id="mode-2g-option-33923a49-d134-b2f9-1048-786edd639f99" name="" display="802.11b/g/n/ax mixed" class="combobox-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-index="0"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">802.11b/g/n/ax mixed</span></label></li><li class="combobox-list   "><label for="mode-2g-option-ee4ceb5e-a134-b2f9-1048-786f7be50e7a" type="single" class="combobox-label single"><input id="mode-2g-option-ee4ceb5e-a134-b2f9-1048-786f7be50e7a" name="" display="802.11b/g/n/ax/be mixed" class="combobox-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-index="1"><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">802.11b/g/n/ax/be mixed</span></label></li></div><span class="text-wrap-after"></span></div><div widget="errortip" error-cls="" id="mode-2g_errortip" class="combobox-error-tips widget-error-tips" style="display: none;"><span class="widget-error-tips-delta"></span><div class="widget-error-tips-wrap"><span class="widget-error-tips-delta"></span><div class="content error-tips-content"></div></div></div><div class="widget-tips combobox-tips " style="display: none;"><div class="content tips-content"></div></div></div></div>

combobox-list    False
combobox-list    False
combobox-checkbox False
combobox-checkbox False
```

By the way, the combo is showing a selected value, not the default string like 'Please select'.

Answer (score 0):

In provided HTML none of items are selected.

To get `is_selected` state correctly, you should call it on input element.

```py
items = ele.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.combobox-checkbox")
for item in items:
    print(item.is_selected())
```

or as a second option you can get input property `checked`

```py
items = ele.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.combobox-checkbox")
for item in items:
    print(item.get_property('checked'))
```

both of implementations would return `True` is checkbox is checked and `False` if it is not.

You can test it there. I just copied your structure and checked one of checkboxes as an example, how it works.

```py
url = "https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-09-02.html"
driver.get(url)

ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-bind="{wireless24g.hwmode}"]')
items = ele.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.combobox-checkbox")
for i in range(len(items)):
    print(f"Element at index {i} is checked: {items[i].get_property('checked')}")
    print(f"Element at index {i} is selected: {items[i].is_selected()}")
print('Selecting first checkbox')
items[0].click()
for i in range(len(items)):
    print(f"Element at index {i} is checked: {items[i].get_property('checked')}")
    print(f"Element at index {i} is selected: {items[i].is_selected()}")
```

Comment: I appreciate that works when you click from code but it doesn't help when I select a option from the web page using the browser. As you say, there doesn't seem to be anything in the HTML which indicates which item has been selected.

Comment: @quite68 are you sure, that you are checking input element and it is checked? As far as it's frontend logic. And after checkbox is checked, it's property updated automatically. And the same it works with DOM that you provided.

Comment: @quite68 when you getting checked property on checked input, it still doesn't work?

`checked = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].checked',items[i])` , where items[i] is you input element

Comment: I never get the checked property set. I select one of the drop down items manually in the browser but there's still nothing in the HTML retrieved by selenium to indicate which item is selected.